# Share files between users in the same Debian machine by using Samba

Tags: linux, debian, samba, shared-folders

I have a Debian machine with a root user, and several other users that do not have root privileges. Each user has its own directory, and I would like to set a shared directory for all these users.

Is it possible to set a shared directory for the root user and other users within the same machine by using Samba? If so, how?

So far, I set a Samba password for my root user, called koala. So I ran the following command: `smbpasswd -a koala`

Created a directory to be shared: `mkdir /home/koala/shr-folder`

And added this to the end of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[shr-folder]
path = /home/koala/shr-folder
valid users = koala
read only = no
```

How can I share this folder with a user called `usr1` that exists in the same machine as the root user `koala`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a samba share and not just use a directory with appropriate permissions? Otherwise you would just need to include them in the `valid users` list. See also [Chapter 9. Users and Security in the documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html).

Answer (score 2):

Samba (SMB = [Server Message Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)) is a Microsoft *network protocol* for sharing files etc. between *different* computers. Because it was developed by Microsoft, it's not a very good fit with the way Linux handles permissions etc.

So while it's *possible* to do what you want with Samba on a single machine, I wouldn't recommend it.

The classical way to do it is to create a new group, make all user who should have access to the shared directory members of this group, make a directory *directly* under `/home`, i.e. `/home/groupx`, use `chgrp` to set the new group for this directory, and use `chmod g+rw` and `chmod g+s` to set the setgid bit on this directory. The latter will cause all new files to also belong to the new group. Then all members of this group can freely share files.